React Native iOS modal/popup disappears immediately
I am developing a native module to integrate payments.
After debugging with xcode and using symbolic breakpoints I found the source of the issue, but I want to understand why this is happening, and how to fix the issue.
I use a UIViewController to present this modal, but the type of the view controller is RCTModalHostViewController, because the UI library I am using (UI Kitten) is doing somthing to change the view controller's type.
When I remove UI Kitten, the view controller type returns UIViewController again, and the modal does not disappear.
How do I get the instance of the view controller?
I use this method RCTPresentedViewController() from this header <React/RCTUtils.h>.
The relevant part of the code is here:
internal class OppwaHandler: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, OPPThreeDSEventListener, PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate {
    // constants
    let viewController = RCTPresentedViewController()

    // ... some irrelevant code

    public func onApplePay(params: ApplePayParams) -> String {
         // ... some irrelevant code
        if let rootViewController = self.viewController {
            if let vc = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: request) as PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController? {
                vc.delegate = self
            
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    rootViewController.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                return "Ok. reached end of ok logic"
            } else {
                return "Apple Pay not supported."
            }
        }else{
            return "Not showing view controller"
        }

When using UI KItten the type of rootViewController is RCTModalHostViewController, but when I remove UI Kitten its type is UIViewController and the modal does not disappear.
Versions:

Expo: 50.0.17
React Native: 0.73.6
UI Kitten: 5.1.2

General info:

The modal in question is Apple Pay window.
I am integrating Apply Pay with Oppwa.


To answer my own question.
iOS does not allow more than one modal to be presented. And I was already presenting a modal without knowing it (the Loading Component).
